# Qual a diferença entre "require" e "require-dev"?

Tags: json, composer, grunt

No **Composer**, **Grunt** por exemplo, tem o `require` e o `require-dev`. A minha dúvida é qual a diferença entre eles?

**Exemplo phpBB**

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3,<7.0",
    "lusitanian/oauth": "0.2.*",
    "symfony/config": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/console": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/dependency-injection": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/event-dispatcher": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/http-kernel": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/routing": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/yaml": "2.3.*",
    "twig/twig": "1.*"
},
"require-dev": {
    "fabpot/goutte": "1.0.*",
    "phing/phing": "2.4.*",
    "phpunit/dbunit": "1.3.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "4.1.*",
    "sami/sami": "1.*",
    "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "2.*",
    "symfony/browser-kit": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/css-selector": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/debug": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/dom-crawler": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/filesystem": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/finder": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/http-foundation": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/process": "2.3.*"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lista de pacotes na chave `require` contém os pacotes essenciais para o seu projeto, que devem ser instalados em qualquer um dos ambientes (produção, homologação, testes etc.) em que ele irá rodar. O comando `composer install` instala esses pacotes.

Já a lista de pacotes na chave `require-dev` contém apenas os pacotes que devem ser instalados em ambiente de desenvolvimento, e são instalados usando-se o comando `composer install --dev`. Deve-se evitar instalar esses pacotes em ambiente de produção uma vez que, já que nunca deverão ser usados nesse tipo de ambiente, acabam adicionando arquivos desnecessários ao projeto.

Answer (score 1):

[Tendo isto em conta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16679589/whats-the-difference-between-require-and-require-dev). Os pacotes `require-dev` não são necessários para seu projeto trabalhar e não devem ser incluidos na versão que entrar em produção. Estes pacotes por convenção são apenas para desenvolvimento e testes.